# How to filter dataframe for blank rows only in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, na

I see a lot of scripts that filter *out* empty/blank rows, but I don't see any that show how to *keep* blank rows. I have 27 columns and want to filter/subset my dataset for rows that have NA values in *all* columns.

Comment: Take a look at `?all` and `?is.na`, e.g. `df[apply(df, 1, \(x) all(is.na(x))),]` or `df[rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df),]`

Comment: To expand on Andre's comment, `df[rowSums(!is.na(df)) == 0,]` seems the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:5,
    b = 1:5,
    c = 1:5
)

# create the NA rows
df[2,] <- NA
df[4,] <- NA

# if the number of NA values in a row equals the number of columns in the dataframe, keep the row
df %>%
  {filter(df, rowSums(is.na(.)) == ncol(.))}
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
      a     b     c
  <int> <int> <int>
1    NA    NA    NA
2    NA    NA    NA
```

---

Another way:

```
filter(df, if_all(everything(), is.na))
```

Comment: I am not trying to remove NA rows, I am trying to remove everything except NA rows

Comment: @BrendaThompson that's what my code does- remove everything except NA rows

Comment: oh, I was confused by your comment in the script, disregard my comment.

Comment: what is the role of the period in `is.na(.)` and `ncol(.)` ?

Comment: sorry about that! I don't know why I wrote that

Comment: dot is a placeholder for the previous argument

Comment: so in this case, df

Comment: the curly brackets mean when you are using the pipe, instead of the previous thing becoming the first argument of the function, you can put it wherever you like (using the `.`

Comment: oh that's so useful to know! I often see syntax that deviates from the syntax in the function documentation and I'm like, where did this come from, lol. thank you for the explanation